# form builder: redirect to contact after creation

Tags: formbuilder

I'm using Form Builder to create a simple contact creation form that is available as a dashlet. I'd like to redirect to the newly created contact upon form submission -- but it's not clear if any variables or tokens are available and can be used in the post-submit page config setting. Documentation is also a bit sparse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the form settings section of any form, there’s now a ‘Post-Submit Page’ option -
[image: Post-submit option]

/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=[Individual1.0.id]

Token was available in the drop down menu.